# WP8: how to get back an IntPtr in c++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, unity-game-engine, native

I'm developping a plugin for winphone 8 with Unity3d using c++ and directx.
I'm right now stuck because I don't know how to pass an IntPtr type from my c# code to my c++ code. It's actually much easier for android or iOS plugin since we can get back the data as a void*. 
However in a Windows Phone Runtime Component project it's not possible. From what I read I've got to use winRT types. I've already search

Here are my code samples:

In C#:

```
public delegate void WP8EnableTextureDrawing(System.IntPtr texture);
private WP8EnableTextureDrawing wp8EnableTextureDrawing;

public void SetWP8TextureDrawingFunc(WP8EnableTextureDrawing func){

    wp8EnableTextureDrawing = func;
}

//...

wp8EnableTextureDrawing(targetTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr());
```

In the c++ header file I matches the delegate this way:

```
static void enableTextureDrawing(Platform::Object ^texturePtr);
```

But the compiler throws this error ->
No overload for 'WP8TextureDrawing.TextureDrawing.enableTextureDra wing(object)' matches delegate 'NativeTextureDrawer.WP8EnableTextureDrawing'

I hope someone who has already get his hands in this would help me out.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

System.IntPtr ins't Platform::Object^.
You should use ToInt64() or ToInt32() from IntPtr
for memory address getting and sending it to the native code.